# Entity Framework crear campo Image

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework code first tengo la necesidad de crear un campo image en SQL Server. Lo que intento hacer mediante EF crear un campo Image en la base de datos.

```
 public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }
```

Clase ProductoMap

```
Property(c => c.Imagen).HasMaxLength(8).HasColumnOrder(8);
```

¿Que debo poner en ProductoMap para que en la db me cree un campo de tipo Image?

Comment: ¿Te refieres al tipo de datos } `image` de SQL Server? Si es así te cuento que ese tipo de datos ya está obsoleto, en su lugar deberías usar `varbinary(max)`

Comment: No se define ninguna MaxLength cuando se trata de un campo binario. No tienes que poner nada en ProductoMap

Comment: Gracias solo modifique a Property(c => c.Imagen).IsRequired().HasColumnOrder(7); Y se creo en la db varbinary(Max) y funciono excelente, una pregunta por curiosidad en SQL 2005 hay ese tipo de dato varbinary(Max), estoy trabajando con SQL 2014 no tengo problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `.HasColumnType()` para hacer explícito el tipo de dato que esparas que el Fluent API mapee.

Sin embargo el tipo `image` ya está obsoleto:

De : [ntext, text e image (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187993.aspx)

> Los tipos de datos ntext, text e image se quitarán en una versión futura de Microsoft SQL Server. Evite su uso en nuevos trabajos de desarrollo y piense en modificar las aplicaciones que los usan actualmente. Utilice nvarchar(max), varchar(max) y varbinary(max) en su lugar.

En su lugar usa el tipo `varbinary(max)`

```
Property(c => c.Imagen).HasColumnType("varbinary(max)");
```

Aunque de todas maneras esto no es necesario debido a que el tipo de dato de SQL Server utilizado por defecto para mapear el `byte[]` ya es `varbinary(max)`

Si de todas maneras por compatibilidad o que se yo deseas usar `image` simplemente usa ese tipo:

```
Property(c => c.Imagen).HasColumnType("image");
```

Answer (score 1):

No tiene que definir nada en ProductoMap

[[Entity Framework] Code First – Convention for Properties/Columns](https://soabubblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/cf-convention-properties/)

Por convencion una propiedad del tipo `byte[]` es un `varbinary`